# send data:image/png;base64 form javascript to servlet and receiving from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, canvas, file-upload, base64

i want to convert canvas into image and send that image to my server. so what i want is that collect canvas from html page using javascript and then send that data to my servlet where i can perform upload image on server.

thank you...

```
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:701)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:455)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:667)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

```js
 function saveImg() {
    var canvasData = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL("image/png");
    alert(canvasData);    
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "Signature?image=" + canvasData;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
    var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    response = response.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");
    response = response.trim();
    if(response === "Bill Receipt sent successfully"){
    alert("Bill Mailed Successfully");
    }
    else{
    alert("Something's not good please contact the admin");
    }
    }

    };
    try{
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }catch(e){alert("unable to connect to server");
   }
```

```
public class Signature extends Canvas {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String image = request.getParameter("image");

        System.out.println(image);

    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: how can i upload signature using canvas on my server. i am using netbean. and my framework is JSP.

Comment: Use POST method, put image data to request body, not to URL.